# Read email with embeded images from gmail and send it again with PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I'm fetching emails from gmail with

```
$accountUser        = 'my@mail.com';
$accountPassword    = 'mypass';
$accountHost       = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';

$mbox = imap_open($accountHost, $accountUser, $accountPassword);
```

and obtaining the content with

```
$body               = imap_body($mbox , $idMensaje) ;
```

then, I'm trying to send the same email with PHPMailer as follows

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                               
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
$mail->Username = $accountUser;                   
$mail->Password = $accountPassword;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587;                                    
$mail->setFrom($accountUser, 'EMAIL');      
$mail->addAddress('another@mail.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;           
$mail->isHTML(true);             

$mail->Subject = 'New Mail';
$mail->Body    = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Mail Error ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Mail Sended';
```

The mail is sent but with the text

```
--089e01494136bcca590503210698
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary9e01494136bcca570503210697

--089e01494136bcca570503210697
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

... followed by the email body, everything broken and the embeded images in base64
```

any suggestion, tip, or advice is welcome.

Comment: You will be ending up with a complete RFC822 email message in $body, not a simple text or HTML part that PHPMailer is expecting. In order to do this reliably, PHPMailer would need to support artbitrary MIME structures, which it doesn't, so you'll need to dismantle the message with a MIME parser, then pass the relevant pieces to PHPMailer.

Comment: If you want to forward the message intact, you could do so by attaching it to a new PHPMailer instance as a complete RFC822 message.